# Compiling sphinx search on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: macos, sphinx

I am trying to install sphinx on Lion.
I've tried versions 0.9.9, 2.0.2, and trunk (as of now).
However, `./configure` breaks: "`universal endianness not supported`".
I have only seen this configure error on Lion; Snow Leopard and earlier OSX versions work fine.

I've tried forcing little endian via CFLAGS etc., but I'm not sure what flag needs tweaking. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does `./configure --help | grep -ie universal -ie endian` show any related configuration options?

Comment: Unfortunately no documented configure options, no :-( For now, I've worked around it by compiling on Snow Leopard and copying the binaries over to Lion. Ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it via MacPorts. Caveat is that your mysql / postgres must also have been installed from ports to satisfy a dependency.

If you're on Lion, the comment in this bug report is useful:

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31666

`sudo port clean sphinx;`
`sudo port install sphinx configure.compiler=llvm-gcc-4.2`